# Light switch controls outside outlet, no light in living room

Tags: electrical

My living room has three switches on one panel. One controls the porch light. One controls the light over the steps leading upstairs. And the third controls an outside outlet.

My living room has no light fixtures. The house was built in the 1930's. We are looking into doing some remodeling and adding light is one of the things we want to do.

My question is how expensive it would be to have the switch rewired to control an overhead light if even possible. Or should we look into a remote controlled ceiling fan/light.

Comment: We have no idea where you are in the world, so knowing the electrician labor rates is impossible. Then we have no idea how far the light fixture may be to the wall with the switch, nor what materials they are made from, or what extent you plan to do remodeling...in a nut shell we need far more info to give an answer that is more than a guess.  Your best bet is to call for quotes from a licensed electrician.

Comment: Reusing the switch may actually be harder than putting in a new switch. And wired in switch isn't the only answer; my LR has a swage-style lamp setup, hanging by a chain with a cord over to a smart dimmer plugged into an outlet, and I mostly operate it by voice control.

Comment: you will need 2 cables run. One in the Attic to the light, and one from the light to the switch, how much ? get a quote

Answer (score 0):

Remote controlled or not, you still need power to the new ceiling light.

For that go to the attic above the living room and see what cables you have there.

While you are up there check where the cable for the stairs light comes from.

You could use that one for the living room light on the same switch..

So far all this was a DIY with some electrical experience. And experience not to step between the beams onto drywall ceiling.

Advantage you can do it your self. Disadvantage the stair light will switch with living room light.

The best but most difficult option is to run new cables for light and switch.

Comment: This presumes you have attic epac above the living room. If you don't, cable can be run up to from the basement to the switch, and with some holes and repair can be frun from there to the fixture (or vice versa if you absolutely insist upon a switch loop). Or you can go with surface wiring, as in my swage lamp solution, plugging that you into a switch outlet... which avoids the ceiling run.